# Getting JSON server answer from Thread into AlertDialog

Tags: android, multithreading

**Situation**

I have an app that scans QR codes, sends the contents to a php script on our server and receives a JSON object as String back.

**Problem**

The server communication happens in a Thread, and the JSON object is returned inside that Thread as well, of course. This wouldn't be an issue if I could create and deal with the AlertDialog in the Thread, but that doesn't seem to be possible. I need to get this result back in my main Thread somehow, but I haven't been able to find a working solution yet. This is how my code runs at the moment (slightly simplified):

```
    public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            final Barcode barcode;

            if (barcodes.size() > 0) {
                barcode = barcodes.valueAt(0);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Check.class);
                intent.putExtra("code", barcode.displayValue);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
```

Then, in Check:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String code = intent.getStringExtra("code");
    Log.i("RESULT", code);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder sb;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://website.com/scan.php?code=" + code);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                Log.i("OUTPUT", url.toString());
                osw.write(url.toString());
                osw.flush();

                reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                Log.i("SB", sb.toString());
            } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                Log.i("URL", mue.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.i("CONNECTION", ioe.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("FINALLY", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    //Get sb
}
```

It logs sb.toString as expected.

**What I've tried**

Passing sb to a separate class that holds global variables: resulted in NULL. Creating a class that implements Runnable and getting the variable with getResult(): results in error. Volatile variables: results in error.

Please ask me anything that isn't clear.

**Update**

For those who advise me to use `AsyncTask`, maybe you see something in my code that I do not:

```
    private static class Comm extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {
    Hub hub = new Hub();
    String answer = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://website.com/scan.php?code=" + params[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            Log.i("OUTPUT", url.toString());
            osw.write(url.toString());
            osw.flush();

            reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            answer = sb.toString();
            Log.i("SB", answer);

        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            Log.i("URL", mue.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.i("CONNECTION", ioe.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("FINALLY", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String code) {
        super.onPostExecute(code);
        hub.result = code;
    }
}
```

I still get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` with this task.

---

**Solved**

If anyone has this issue: Be sure to call your `AsyncTask` with `[yourtask].execute(params)`, not `doInBackground`.

Comment: Why don't you use built in solutions like `AsyncTask` or `AsyncTaskLoader`?

Comment: Use AsyncTask, example below: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask. Remember to handle configuration changes ( such as screen rotations) during network call.

Comment: I can't seem to return a String with doInBackground. It must be an issue with my Android Studio. Any example I use that works for others gives the same error: attempting to use incompatible return type.

Comment: Edit: Using AsyncTask for server communication gives NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: Network on main thread is when you try to update the UI from AsyncTask, execute that part of code to update UI in `onPostExecute` method of Asynctask

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException is when you try to perform network operations on your main thread. I'm thinking since `AsyncTask` is not technically a Thread, it still counts as main thread network operations. I updated my question to show how I'm using my `AsyncTask` at the moment.

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.